# Change in probability complexity when adding 2 "wildcards" (jokers) to a standard 52 card deck

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am wondering what happens to the complexity of probability when "wildcard" conditions are allowed in random card draws.  For example, the probabilities of the $5$ card poker hands from a standard $52$ card deck are well known.  These can also be verified rather easily on a computer by generating all possible $5$ card hands and just counting up how many of each type of hands there are (full houses, flushes...).

So my question is what happens if we allow $2$ jokers into the deck (thus making it a 54 card deck) and look for those same 5 card hands?  Is it now less of a task to simulate them on a computer and count them that way vs. using enhanced (to handle the jokers) mathematical formulas?  Does simulation software such as Mathematica allow for such wildcard conditions?

Let's take an actual example...  In a regular $52$ card deck, the chance of getting $4$ of a kind (such as K,K,K,K) on a random $5$ card draw is $624$ / $2,598,960$. Suppose we add $2$ jokers to the deck such that they can be counted as any card not already in the hand with the purpose of making the 5 card hand the best it can possibly be.  So for example, if we were to get K,K,A,Joker,Joker, we would then use the $2$ jokers to get our $4$ of a kind (K,K,K,K,A).  So obviously it is much easier to get a better hand with the jokers but I suspect it would make the math (and simulations) much more difficult.

So what would be the probability of getting $4$ of a kind with $2$ jokers in the deck of $54$ cards?  Note that K,K,K, Joker, Joker counts as $4$ of a kind because we are not introducing "new" winning hands such as $5$ of a kind.  Only the "standard" $5$ card poker hands are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Since given the two jokers added to deck, we can break up probability into getting four kings with no jokers, one jokers, and two jokers Thus we have 
$$P(4\textrm{ kings})=\frac{1}{54 \choose 5}\left({48\choose 1}{2\choose 0}{4\choose 4}+{48\choose 1}{2\choose 1}{4 \choose 3}+{48\choose 1}{2\choose 2}{4 \choose 2}\right)$$

Comment: If anyone sees anything that is wrong or should be fixed please point out.

Comment: By "jacks" you mean "jokers".

Comment: oh nice catch thank you

Comment: I think you missed $2$ cases: the player has $3$ kings and $2$ jokers, thus counting as $4$ kings, or the player has $4$ kings and $1$ joker, also counting as $4$ kings.

Comment: So it seems you need to add a ${2 \choose 2}{4 \choose 3}$ to the $3$ king case and add ${2 \choose 1}{4 \choose 4}$ to the $4$ king case.  Adding $2$ jokers would likely make it more fun and interesting for a Texas Hold 'em game between some small number of players such as $2$ or $3$ because it would be much easier to get good "standard" 5 card poker hands that way such as $4$ of a kind.  It would even be possible for 2 players to both get quad kings if the pair of jokers are in the community cards and they each have 2 kings in hand.

Comment: David you are correct. For some reason I assumed you were asking for exactly 4 of a kind, but yes I must add those cases. I also wonder if there is more efficent way to calculate probabilities because this method seems quite tedious

Comment: Yea definitely adding jokers to texas hold em would definitely changed the probabilities quite a bit